# Операция замены в редакторе vim

Tags: linux, vim

получаю первый опыт в работе с редактором vim
Задача следующая
С помощью операции замены в конец каждого слова, находящегося между косыми черточками / .. /, добавить звёздочку *.
Не могли бы вы пожалуйста подсказать, как мне обозначить слова находящиеся между слэшами

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Команда:

```
:%s/\/\([^\/]*\)\//\/\1*\//g
```

Разберем на части

- `%s/../../g` - запустить замену по всем строкам. Флаг `g` в конце - заменять все совпадения в каждой строке.
- `\/` - это экранирование символов, которые используются как разделители в команде замены.
- `\(..\)` - это указание, что совпадение нужно запомнить, чтоб можно было использовать при замене используя `\1`. Тут '1' - номер совпадения по порядку.
- `[^\/]*` - все символы кроме, собственно `/` (опять же с экранированием)

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало!

Comment: `\w` Регулярное выражение для слова.